# Does C++ have hoisting of class?

Tags: c++, class, c++11

I've heard that it's illegal to implement a member function in a different scope such as...

```cpp
class Foo{
   public:
      Foo();
}

int main(){
   Foo :: Foo(){   // implementation must be held in same scope where class is: global scope
      std::cout << "Hello" << std::endl;
   }
}
```

So I thought that defining a class inside the main function would make it possible to implement the method inside main.

```cpp
#include <iostream>

int main() {

class Person {
  public:
    std::string name;
    int age;
    Person(std::string name, int age);
};

Person ::Person(std::string name, int age)
    : name(name), age(age) {
    std::cout << "Person class created as" << name << " " << age << std::endl;
}

    Person yun("yun", 18);

    std::cout << yun.name;

    Person *john = new Person("John", 15);
}
```

But the code above creates an error: `qualified-id in declaration before '(' token`
which is the same error I've seen when the method is implemented in a different scope.

Does this have something to do with `hoisting` that I've seen at JavaScript? So that the class definition goes outside of main?

Comment: C++ doesn't allow nested functions. If you declare `Person` inside `main` then you'll have to write any `Person` member functions inside `Person`.

Comment: Hoisting really doesn't make sense in C++. There's a long tradition of only allowing code to be compiled for which at least a *declaration* has been provided, if not a definition. C is prepared to assume a lot of things, but those generally produce warnings that should be treated as errors.